# Read XML data into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have created an Adobe LiveCycle form that collects the form data into an XML file.  I would like to read this XML data into a SQL Server 2008 database.  The format of the data is a parent table with 2 child tables.  What are the options for getting the data into a database.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233/the-best-way-to-shred-xml-data-into-sql-server-database-columns?rq=1

Comment: Also, some details of XML and table structure required for detailed answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing data from XML file to SQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795787/importing-data-from-xml-file-to-sql-database)

Comment: I was not able to insert a picture of the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is nearly identical to [Importing data from XML file to SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795787/importing-data-from-xml-file-to-sql-database).

You could try the 2008 version of the [SQL Server Import/Export Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

If you know how to write code, almost every programming language has a way to talk to a database and SQL server should be supported by all of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways read data from xml file For SQL Server 2008

1.Using xquery

2.Using  [OpenXML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175160.aspx)

[How do you read XML column in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815836/how-do-you-read-xml-column-in-sql-server-2008)

[Read XML document stored in SQL Server 2008 R2 with XML datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561296/read-xml-document-stored-in-sql-server-2008-r2-with-xml-datatype)

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/13/sql-server-simple-example-of-reading-xml-file-using-t-sql/

http://blog.wharton.com.au/2011/05/27/part-2-openxml-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it/