# OpenXml returns null for elements inside XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, openxml

```
Declare @xml xml,
@y int
set @xml= '<ContactUpdates>
       <Contact VendorID="4"><LastName>McCrystle</LastName>
       <FirstName>Timothy</FirstName>
       </Contact>
       <Contact VendorID="10">
        <LastName>Flynn</LastName>
        <FirstName>Erin</FirstName>
        </Contact></ContactUpdates>'


Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @y output, @xml;
Select * from openxml(@y,'/ContactUpdates/Contact')
  With (VendorID Varchar(20),
        LastName Varchar(30),
        FirstName Varchar(30))`
```

[image: The result is]

I do not know where has the mistake been done. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Please refer to the link here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561296/read-xml-document-stored-in-sql-server-2008-r2-with-xml-datatype\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mix of both attribute-centric and element centric-projections. The reason why `VendorId` is mapped, but not the two elements, is because attribute centric is the default. In a mixed / complex hierarchy scenario, as [per here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx), you will need to explicitly provide the `xpath` mappings:

```
Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @y output, @xml;
Select * from openxml(@y,'/ContactUpdates/Contact')
  With (VendorID Varchar(20) '@VendorID', -- Attribute
        LastName Varchar(30) 'LastName', -- Element
        FirstName Varchar(30) 'FirstName'); -- Element
```

**Edit**

Something of interest to note is that the `flags` attribute is, well, a bitwise style [flag]. This means you can OR the options together. `1` is attribute centric, and `2` element centric, so `1 | 2 = 3` will give you both:

```
Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @y output, @xml;
Select * from openxml(@y,'/ContactUpdates/Contact', 3)
  With (VendorID Varchar(20),
        LastName Varchar(30),
        FirstName Varchar(30));

-- Remember to release the handle with sp_xml_removedocument
```

I however do not believe this is good practice - it doesn't convey much to the developer, and it possibly has negative performance implications given that it is less specific than the exact xpath.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stuart, if possible can you provide me with a link or example of explicitly providing xpath mappings

Comment: Here's a [good bunch of xpath examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx). TL;DR: `/ContactUpdates/Contact` has already navigated you to the `Contact` element. Attributes in xpath / xsl are prefixed by `@` and elements are unprefixed. Also, have updated, although I would prefer the original answer as it more accurately conveys the intention to a reader and also does not require Sql to guess for you. Pradeep's answer uses XQuery, which is a different approach.

Comment: Thanks Stuart I appreciate your support.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
SELECT VendorID = Container.value('(@VendorID)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       LastName = Container.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       FirstName = Container.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM   (SELECT @xml Columndata) a
       CROSS APPLY Columndata.nodes('/ContactUpdates/Contact') AS T(Container)
```

Edited as per Stuart comment.

```
SELECT VendorID = Container.value('(@VendorID)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       LastName = Container.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       FirstName = Container.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM   @xml.nodes('/ContactUpdates/Contact') AS T(Container)
```

Comment: +1, just note that this changes the technology to `XQuery`. Also, since this is an XML variable, not a table column, you can avoid the `CROSS APPLY` altogether, viz: `FROM   @xml.nodes('/ContactUpdates/Contact') as T(Container)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper, native XQuery support in SQL Server :

```
SELECT
    VendorID = xc.value('@VendorID', 'int'),
    FirstName = xc.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    LastName = xc.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/ContactUpdates/Contact') AS XT(XC)
```

Easily gives you this nice output:

[image]